# print messages (data) from firebase cloud

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firebase cloud
Data means my chatApp's messages.

[image: like this I want to print messages on my screen]

but in my code i got error
[image: see this arrow line in both images]

android studio suggest me to add nullcheck(!) to

final messages = snapshot.data!.documents;

but it not working

Comment: which flutter version u r using?

Comment: flutter version 2.5.0

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Please post your error here. Also, please follow Frank's comment and use formatting tools to do so.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you show me how can I post as an answer not from resource

Comment: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question and the [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for why we should not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Also this is the [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the null-check and fix your typo: `messgeText` => `messageText`.

Comment: it also not working

Answer (score 0):

You r using Flutter 2.5.0 and now for the latest flutter version the syntax are changed for Firebase . Try this way:

```
               final message = snapshot.data!.data()
```

Comment: not working bro

Comment: what's the error msg?

Comment: first erroe suggest to add null check
when add null check then suggest to create new local variable of data

Comment: can u try this one :snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

Comment: no bro it also...